# jQuery keydown CRLF

Tags: javascript, jquery, ascii, barcode-scanner

I have a problem with the jQuery keydown parameters. I use a Barcode Scanner which sends a 12char string and a CR LF at the end. So I would expect the ASCII code 13 for the last call of keydown. What I get is a additional 40 -> 13 40 (CR "(").
In other applications like Notepad++ / C# console applications etc. the CR is recognized as last character.
Here's a sample code:

```
var keys = [];

$(document).keydown(function (e) {
    keys.push(String.fromCharCode(e.which));
});

$(document).keyup(function () {
    if(keys.length == 14)
    {
        handleCode();
    }
});

function handleCode() {
    var div = document.getElementById('out');
    var html = '';
    var numberOfKeys = keys.length;
    //Last 2 keys == CR "("
    for (var i=0; i < (numberOfKeys);i++) {
        html += keys[i];
    }
    div.innerHTML = html;
    keys = [];
}
```

Has anyone an idea why there's an additional "(" (ASCII code 40) at the end?

Edit: I figured out following behavior for a scanner output of "12345CR":

```
Event on TextBox: 
KeyDown: 49 50 51 52 53 13 ('12345CR')
KeyPress: 49 50 51 52 53 13 ('12345CR')
KeyUp: 49 50 51 52 53 13 40 ('12345CR(')

Event on Document:
KeyDown: 49 50 51 52 53 13 40 ('12345CR(')
KeyPress: 49 50 51 52 53 13 ('12345CR')
KeyUp: 49 50 51 52 53 13 40 ('12345CR(')
```

I end up using KeyPress, which works just fine when it's attached to document (I thought it only works on textboxes). But I still wonder, where the 40 ('(') come from.

Here's the updated code, which works fine now:

```
var keys = [];
var startTime;

$(document).keypress(function (e) {    
    keys.push(String.fromCharCode(e.which));
    if(keys.length == 13)
    {
        handleCode();
    }
});

function handleCode() {
    var div = document.getElementById('out');
    var html = '';
var numberOfKeys = keys.length;
    for (var i=0; i < (numberOfKeys);i++) {
        html += keys[i];
    }
    div.innerHTML = html;
    keys = [];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not entirely clear and in any case I have a tough time believing that any browser would get an ASCII code wrong.  I have set up a little [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dm9NE/1/) to test what you are trying to accomplish.  Hopefully, it will help you figure out the problem.

I am using

```
JSON.stringify
```

to show the results in a manner that is probably more useful.

Comment: This leads actually to the same problem. In the textbox everything is fine, I get for example "999123456789". The output of JSON.stringify(html) on the other hand is 999123456789\r( (Note the "("). The problem comes from e.which which gets me a 40 ("(") instead a 10 (LF) at the end. The \\n / \\r defined in info lead to the correct values (10 13)

Comment: I must be missing the point somewhere. See the modified [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dm9NE/2/).  What part of this behavior is wrong?  In Chrome 30 on Windows I type abcde and then CR to get `c65c66c67c68c69c13` which looks right to me.

Comment: I'm also on Chrome 30 (Win). CR isn't the Problem, it's LF. So I get the output "999123456789\r\n" from the scanner. In your updated fiddle I get "999123456789" in the textbox. In the string I get "c57c57c57c49c50c51c52c53c54c55c56c57c13c40" which should be "c13c10" at the end.

Comment: I get it!  Your scanner sends out a character that should be \n but is turning out as &#40; instead. I modified that [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dm9NE/3/) to simulate sending out characters including the newline.  It still turns up correctly as c13.  Perhaps it is the scanner that is sending out the wrong character?

Comment: That was in my mind too, but if that's the case, I should get the "(" (40) everywhere. But, as already stated, in Notepad++, C# applications, browser textboxes etc. I never get a "(". It just bothers me, where this "(" comes from.

Comment: Have to admit, I am stumped :-(.  How does the scanner output reach the browser?

Comment: It seems like, the scanner sends out an CR only at the end. So it should be c57c57c57c49c50c51c52c53c54c55c56c57c13 in your example. I've created 2 other fiddles [FiddleInput](http://jsfiddle.net/Pxq8b) (With Input element, as well as [FiddleDoc](http://jsfiddle.net/Pxq8b/1/) (On document). To test the behavior of the events. It's kinda strange. When I use the events on a input box I get a 40 at the end only on the KeyUp event. If I use the events on the document I got a 40 at the end on KeyUp and KeyDown. KeyPress seems to work fine (ends with CR).